# routing inside VPN address space

Tags: openvpn, linux-networking

I have a LAN with addresses in 192.168.0.0/24 and a VPN server running pritunl (openvpn) on 192.168.0.10 bound correctly to an external address, that works in 10.0.0.0/8 address space.

Clients are connecting successfully and I can access correctly to the 192.168.0.0/24 LAN, but I can't ping clients on the 10.0.0.0/8 space from the LAN (but from the OPENVPN Server it works)

any clue on what I've to set to make it work? I'd like to use vnc on the vpn clients

Answer (score 0):

If the server with openvpn is not the default gateway in your network then computers in the network will send traffic to 10.0.0.0/8 to the gateway (whatever you use as your router / firewall / NAT device) which not knowingly will forward this to its own gateway (from the ISP) and get lost. You need to create a static route in the gateway for 10.0.0.0/8 to 192.168.0.10, that should do the trick...